# How to preserve zeroes in a numeric value when reading into R

Tags: r

I have a tab delimited text file:

```
0730000    John    1    01    225    000    000
```

and when i read it into R

```
stud_stats <- read.delim("student.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

and viewed the dataframe, the value that is displayed is:

```
730000|John|1|1|225|0|0
```

The numeric values with zeroes in the initial text file have been altered in the dataframe. How do i preserve the numeric value to retain the zeroes when reading into the R dataframe?

I want the following exact value in the dataframe, just like the text file.

```
0730000|John|1|01|225|000|000
```

Comment: You can define the read column as character to do so. E.g. you can write something like: `data <- read.table("student.txt", colClasses=c("character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character"), sep = "\t", ...)`

Comment: One approach could be to use the `readr` package function `read_tsv("student.txt", col_names = F)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the column values, for example by using `data.table::fread`:

```
> data.table::fread('book1.txt', colClasses = rep('character', 7))
     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1: 073000 John    1   01  225  000  000
```

Or by using base R (but `fread` is better),

```
read.table('book1.txt', colClasses = rep('character', 7), header = TRUE)
```